# How do I locate elements in the same row as another in a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am making a page that contains a table with a button to add a row. It is a table for users to input data, and will eventually be submitted to a database.

Currently, I have a price and a quantity field in each row. When either of them change, I want to calculate the total and write it to another cell.

This is my event handler (wrapped in `$(document).ready()`):

```
$(".quantity_input, .price_input").change(function () {
    console.log(this.value);
    cal_total();
});
```

This is my current code:

```
function cal_total() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.value))) {

      alert("You must enter a numeric value.");
      this.value = "";
      return;
    }

    var cell = this.parentNode;
    var row = cell.parentNode;
    var total = parseFloat($("#items_table tr").eq(row.index).find("td").eq(3).find("input").first().val()) * parseFloat($("#items_table tr").eq(row.index).find("td").eq(4).find("input").first().val());

    if (!isNaN(total)) {
      $("#items_table tr").eq(row.index).find("td").eq(5).html(total.toFixed(2));
    }
}
```

And this is what the inputs look like:

```
 <input type='text' class='fancy_form quantity_input' name='quantities[]' size='4' style='text-align:center;border-bottom:none;'>
```

In addition to my original question, the event is never fired. Can anyone see why?

But more importantly, is this the best way to retrieve the values? I really don't think so but I cant come up with anything more clever.

Thank you!

Comment: The first problem that I see is that inside cal_total() you use a "this" that is not referenced to any object, thus this.value cannot work. I didn't understand what you pretend this function to do really

Comment: "this" is set. Jquery event handlers always return the element that called it. (can't find where i read that, so I may be wrong)

Comment: As far I see, the cal_total() function isn't in the same execution context, thus the "this" variable is referenced to the funciton cal_tot() itself. When you create a funciton, "this" is referenced to the function itself, that in javascript is an object. You have to PASS the object with something like "cal_total( this )", define "function cal_total( elem ) {" and use "elem" in place of "this". Just for start. And I didn't understand what you finally require the cal_tot() to do

Comment: cal_total takes 2 numbers, multiplies them, then puts the result in a cell in a table. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: If you post your html and the result you expect after some modification, we can better understand your needs and help you

Comment: I would make it so that you recalculate everything (by looping through all the rows) otherwise you would need to know if you are changing the values (to subtract the old value before adding your new value).  Also as you say these rows are being added dynamically, I would delegate the input change event (otherwise you will need to rebind every time you add a new row)

Comment: you have to pass paremeter to calc_total to define input or tr

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass paremeter to calc_total to define input or tr

try this code

```js
 
$(".quantity_input, .price_input").change(function () {
   $(".quantity_input, .price_input").change(function () {
       cal_total(this);
        });
   });
   function cal_total(elem){
     var row=$(elem).closest("tr")
  var quantity=row.find(".quantity_input").val()-0
   var price=row.find(".price_input").val()-0
   var total=quantity * price
   row.find(".totl_input").val(total)
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
    <input  class="quantity_input" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input  class="price_input" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input  class="totl_input" />
  </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
    <input  class="quantity_input" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input  class="price_input" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input  class="totl_input" />
  </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
    <input  class="quantity_input" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input  class="price_input" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input  class="totl_input" />
  </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```